# Why doesn't the device token field get set sometimes with Parse installation

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

Noticed that sometimes the deviceToken field doesn't get set on android or ios even though we give permissions on the client.  Is there a built in delay or know use cases where the deviceToken doesn't get set with push permissions in parse?